# Передать переменную из php в ajax, и после из ajax в php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Есть три файла load_messages.php (вывод сообщений) , chat.php(сама страница с чатом), add_mess.php (через что сохраняются сообщения в базу) .
Суть такая. Нужно не обновляя страницу переключаться между диалогами (см. скриншот).
[image: скриншот чата]

Далее. По нажатию на диалог слева, например "Админ", открываются сообщения с Админом. По нажатию на кого то другого, соответственно с другим.
Код который в chat.php .

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  //Загружаем библиотеку JQuery
  google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
  google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");

  //Функция отправки сообщения
  function send()
  {
    //Считываем сообщение из поля ввода с id mess_to_add
    var mess=$("#mess_to_send").val();
    
 
    // Отсылаем паметры
       $.ajax({
     
                type: "GET",
                url: "add_mess.php",
                data:"mess="+mess,
                // Выводим то что вернул PHP
                success: function(html)
    
    
        {
          //Если все успешно, загружаем сообщения
          load_messes();
          //Очищаем форму ввода сообщения
    
          $("#mess_to_send").val('');
    $("#chat-app").scrollTop(20000);
                }
        });
  }



 //Функция загрузки сообщений
 function load_messes()
 {
  
   $.get('load_messages.php', {id:<?php echo $k['id'];?>}, function(data) {
                    $('#user_data').html(data);
     
    
    {
     //Очищаем форму ввода
       $('#user_data').html(data);
     //Прокручиваем блок вниз(если сообщений много)
     $("#chat-app").scrollTop(20000);
                }
        });
 }
 
 

</script>
```

Код load_messages.php

```html
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
//Подключаемся к базе данных
    include("bd.php");
 
//Записываем все в переменные
    $user_id=$_POST['id'];



$use=$_SESSION['login'];
$usrid=$_SESSION['id'];
// $delbtn = '<button class="btnDeleteAction" name="delete" onClick="callCrudAction(`delete`,echo $comments[$k]["id"];)">Delete</button>';
//Выбираем все сообщения
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (user_id='$user_id' and from_user_id='$usrid') or (user_id='$usrid' and from_user_id='$user_id' ) ORDER BY 'date_create' LIMIT 45 ");

//Выводим все сообщения на экран
while($d=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{ 
  echo '
  
   ';
          
          
          if ($d['user_id'] == $usrid or $use == $d['login'])
            {
                                           echo '<div class="direct-chat-msg right mb-30">
      
      <div class="direct-chat-text">
     <p>';echo $d['message']; echo'</p>';
                 // <p class="direct-chat-timestamp"><time datetime="2018">';echo $d['date_create']; echo'</time></p>
     echo ' </div>
     
    </div>';
            }
                                                else {
          
          echo '<div class="direct-chat-msg mb-30" >
      <div class="clearfix mb-15">
     <span class="direct-chat-name">Админ #1</span>

      </div>
      <img class="direct-chat-img avatar" src="images/user1-128x128.jpg" alt="message user image">
      <div class="direct-chat-text">
     <p>';echo $d['message']; echo'</p>
     <p class="direct-chat-timestamp"><time datetime="2018">';echo $d['date_create']; echo'</time></p>
      </div>
      </div>';
          
         
     }    
         
       
}
}
?>
```

Код сохранения вряд ли нужен, с ним все в порядке.
Необходимо понять, как сделать по клику на диалог, вывод сообщений в чат именно с этим диалогом.

Answer (score 0):

создаем атрибут на контейнер с блоком пользователя `data-login="<?php echo $user['login']?>"`
Далее в js обрабатываем события клика на этот блок, с помощью js отправляем ajax c параметром  `login` берем его из `data-login`, на сервере обрабатываем запрос с выборкой и отправляем полученные данные в наш файлик с чатом, а потом просто обрабатываем и добавляем контент